# The requested resource /assets was not found on this server

Tags: laravel, routes

I get this message

> The requested resource /assets was not found on this server.

when I visit this link http://127.0.0.1:8000/assets.

I have these route in my web.php

`Route::resource('assets', AssetController::class)->except(['destroy', 'create', 'update']);`

and have more than 30 modules, I can access them all but the asset one is the only one giving me this message

Comment: do you have a folder named `assets` in the `public` folder? .. and you are serving this with `artisan serve`?

Comment: yeah I do have a folder named assets where I store my css and js file in my public folder

Comment: I got your pointed, I renamed my routes so it doesn't have the same name as the assets folder and it worked. Thank u!